# Can the secondary voltage of this old transformer be derived?

Tags: transformer, magnetics, core, calculation, parameters

Images are of an unknown "4808" PCB-mounted transformer. It has an open 240 VAC primary.

Data: EI48 core, around 12-15VA. The center-tapped secondary is 15Ω-CT-15Ω and 1.6H-CT-1.6H according to an LCR meter. The primary terminates as tri-filar but seems to be laid down individually. The secondary is uni-filar 0.27 mm / 10.6 mil.

Is there any way the output voltage can be approximated from this data?

It's powering a very old board which uses a UA709CL op-amp rated for +/-18 V, but that is not directly from these windings; the transformer could be anything from 9-0-9 to 48-0-48 or higher. Any ideas?

[image: 4808 transformer 1 of 2]

[image: 4808 transformer 2 of 2]

Comment: You say it's a 240 V primary, so, apply the designed primary voltage and perhaps a reasonable secondary load (start with high resistance--either power resistors or an electronic load in constant resistance mode (or constant power mode if it has it)--and go down if needed, so you don't overload the transformer) and measure the secondary voltage.

Comment: I would, but the primary is open.

Comment: Dismantle it and compare the ratio of turns - https://smcint.com/transformer-turns-ratio/

Comment: Ah. I didn't understand what you meant at first by "an open 240 V primary". You could count the number of turns, but that would be a job and a half, so probably not the way to go. I think it would be easier, then, to analyze the system the transformer came out of (I'm assuming you're looking for info in order to replace it), and see if you can't work out what voltage it needs to run. The information you have isn't enough to tell--and I'm pretty sure no information you can get from what you have, short of counting windings, would be.

Comment: the open primary may be caused by an open thermal fuse ... remove the cover from the primary windings to see

Comment: ^^^ That.   It's probably a failed thermal fuse.  They're usually not buried too deep... just peeling back the paper insulation may expose it.  You can (temporarily) short-circuit it and then do the voltage test, but don't put that transformer back into service if that indeed is the case.

Comment: Bodgy --> remove the primary (as scrap copper), weigh it, estimate the mean length of 1 average turn, measure the gauge and try and figure out how many turns. Ditto the secondary.